# SPO - SharePoint-Hosted Add-In (Create list from VS)

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, sharepoint-hosted-app

I have created two list from Visual studio and after deployment I added data into these lists(accessed from URL address **addInName/List/**(*listname*)).

After second deployment list loose the data... How to solve this problem? I create this lists in RootWeb(Site Collection) ?

Thank U!

Comment: can you please let me know What do you mean to say by second deployment ?

Comment: next deployment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will overwrite the data and list once you deploy with visual studio. To persist your data you need to publish the add in as .app file with next version and upgrade the existing installed app with that published app.it will upgrade the installed app and will not remove the data from list.